# Initializaiton of Hitatchi LCD

Tags: verilog

Trying to set up the initialization of the HD44780. Is this bad practice to have done it like this? Or is it going to try and send all those lines to LCD_DATA at once?

```
enter code here
always LCD_RW = 1'b0;

initial begin

LCD_RS <= 1'b0;

#15; //delay 15ms until set function

        LCD_DATA <= 8'b001101xx; //set 8 bit function
#4.2;
        LCD_DATA <= 8'b00001100; //turn lcd on, with cursor off and not blinking        
#0.04;
        LCD_DATA <= 8'b00000001; //clear display
#1.53;
        LCD_DATA <= 8'b00000010; //Entry Mode Set, Cursor moves right and output does not shift
#0.04;
 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work. Delays aren't synthesizable; they only work in simulation.

You will need to implement this as clocked logic -- probably some sort of state machine.

Comment: Thought so, I'm very confused on how to set up delays with a state machine. Got any tips? Or references.

Comment: I'm thinking some kind of counter, outputting to a comparator and that sends the signal for when to transition. Maybe?